# Access WebGL constants/enums without context

Tags: javascript, webgl

I find it strange that all WebGL constants are defined as members of the rendering context. This means that if the context is wrapped in some library, accessing those constants becomes problematic.

Is there any reason why I can't define them all explicitly? Or, if they are implementation defined, maybe the first time a context is created, write all enum values to some global object?

Basically, instead of writing `new renderer.Texture(renderer.gl.TEXTURE_2D)` or `new renderer.Texture("TEXTURE_2D")`, I want to write something like `new renderer.Texture(WebGL.TEXTURE_2D)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are free to define them as your own constants. In fact it may make your code faster

```
const TEXTURE_2D = 0x0DE1
...
gl.bindTexture(TEXTURE_2D, someTexture);
```

Is perfectly fine. And, if that code is run through a modern JavaScript compressor it will get turned into this

```
gl.bindTexture(0x0DE1, someTexture);
```

Which will arguably be faster. Faster then `gl.TEXTURE_2D` because using `gl.TEXTURE_2D` the JavaScript engine has to always check that someone didn't assign `gl.TEXTURE_2D` to something else.  Faster than `TEXTURE_2D` because even a const variable represents something being created where as `0x0DE1` definitely does not.

Just because I'll probably get some questions later, my point above about speed is the JavaScript engine has to check every single time you call

```
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE2D, ...)
```

That someone somewhere didn't do

```
 gl.TEXTURE_2D = 123
```

or make a property getter

```
 Object.defineProperty(gl, 'TEXTURE_2D', {
   enumerable: true,
   writable: false,
   get() {
     console.log('TEXTURE_2D was accessed at', (new Error()).stack));
     return 0xDE1;
   }
 });
```

The JavaScript engine can't assume the the `TEXTURE_2D` property was not changed. It has to check every time.

As for `const` there may or may not be a general speed difference but for example if we make a function that returns a function like this

```
function makeFuncThatReturnsValue(value) {
  const v = value;
  return function() {
    return v;
  }
}
```

We can see that every time we call `makeFuncThatReturnsValue` a new `v` will be created and captured in the closure.

Just using a literal directly won't have that issue, nothing will be created. Of course you don't want to use the literal directly, magic numbers are bad, but if you compile your JavaScript with a modern compressor it will swap any `const`s for literals where appropriate.

Running an example through [Google's closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)

Code:

```
const w = {
  TEXTURE_2D: 0x0DE1,
};

gl.bindTexture(w.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

[Result](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250Aconst%2520w%2520%253D%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520TEXTURE_2D%253A%25200x0DE1%252C%250A%257D%253B%250A%250Agl.bindTexture(w.TEXTURE_2D%252C%2520null)%253B%250A%250A):

```
gl.bindTexture(3553,null);
```

Comment: Are they guaranteed to always have the same values? [This gist](https://gist.github.com/szimek/763999) has a list of all values, I could just import them? (I'd need to update the list for webgl 2, though)

Comment: Yes, they are guaranteed to always be the same values. You could also regex them out of [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/) with your favorite editor.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm not sure if they will get optimized away unless I export them all individually (`export const TEXTURE_2D=0x0DE1` as opposed to `export default { TEXTURE_2D: 0x0DE1, ... }`) though. That would be a LOT of exports.

Comment: Why redefine constants from the specification when these values are already defined as `WebGLRenderingContext.TEXTURE_2D` (for example)?

Comment: @grovesNL, that will certainly give you access to the values. It won't give you optimal code.

Comment: @gman I'd hope either the minifier or compiler/JIT optimize read-only properties like this. IMO it's best for applications not to redefine/redistribute constants that already exist in the execution context

Comment: @grovesNL, The compiler has no way to know those values are constant so no it can't optimize that. As far are your coding preferences you can inspect the google maps code and see they are doing it the way I suggested above. Style is opinion though so do whatever you want.

Comment: @gman There are already browser optimizations based on constants defined in the execution context. Minifiers could do this as well if a context could be specified, though I don't know if any support this currently. For example Firefox appears to inline or no-op [all of my test cases](https://esbench.com/bench/5b0c0f4af2949800a0f61c86) consistently, while Chrome doesn't appear to do this yet (the `WebGLRenderingContext` cases never appear to no-op). Even on Chrome it's fast enough (IMO) that this optimization should have negligible impact if `window.` is avoided

Comment: It can't do that because it doesn't know the context your going to run in. In otherwords, until the moment your code is run the browser has no way of knowing what the `WebglRenderingContext` is. It could be defined by a script included before yours. It could be defined by an extension. In fact in can be redefined on the fly. Go into your JS Console and type `WebGLRenderingContext = "abc"` and notice how you've now lost access to the original `WebGLRenderingContext`. The JS engine has to check for that. I doesn't know when new code is going to be loaded, executed, evaled, etc..

Comment: If you'd like a working test [here's one](https://jsperf.com/literal-vs-const-vs-member/1). esbench is problematic as it timesout. Also your test was invalid as it wasn't using a literal which is what I claim is faster. Whether or not using literals is faster now or just the same speed is beside the point. The fact is it "can be" because using a literal no checking has to be done where as not using a literal checking has to be done. If it's not faster now that just means the browser hasn't optimized to that level where as some object will always have to be checked at runtime.

Comment: @gman Thanks for clarifying – I think we are actually in agreement here :-) I agree that the literal _could_ be faster in theory (i.e. if browsers haven't optimized this well), but in practice the performance difference should be negligible for real world use cases as demonstrated by our benchmarks

Comment: Chrome showed a significant difference between `WebGLRenderingContext.SOME_CONSTANT` and all other forms. It was also 10x faster than Firefox for the other forms. But that's not the only reason to use constants and compile to literals. An Uglifier can't compress `WebGLRenderingContext.TEXTURE_2D` since those are defined by the browser where as it can compress `MyGLConstants.TEXTURE_2D` to `3553` which means a smaller download and smaller in memory (since source is always available in JS). So, something that will get compiled to literals is pretty much a win all around.

Comment: How can the compiler optimize your last example, if a const object does imply read-only properties? It can probably analyze your specific context, but in general anyone is free to do `w.TEXTURE_2D=1`.

Anyhow, I can't get webpack to optimize away the constants no matter how I export them, so using `WebGL2RenderingContext` is probably ideal for production, as it reduces unnecessary code (but for development, code completion is really convenient, unless I can figure out how to make VS code understand WebGL2 constants).

Comment: I posted an example in the answer using Google's optimizer. Because it knows you defined your constants object (since you passed it into the compiler) and it knows it's not accessed externally (since you didn't tell it that object was going to be externally accessed) then it can analyze how the object is used, see that it is never modified, and convert into literals (which it does, see example in answer).

Comment: Chromium developer here. Thanks for discovering a performance regression in accessing certain constructors, including WebGLRenderingContext, via the global (window) object. We've repaired it (crbug.com/870959), and it should perform considerably better once again (though still not as fast as some alternatives, like inlining the constant value) from Chrome 70.0.3521.2 onward.

Answer (score 4):

You can access them using `WebGLRenderingContext` and `WebGL2RenderingContext` without creating an instance of a context. For example:

```js
console.log(WebGLRenderingContext.TEXTURE_2D); // 3553
```